# How to refresh a GridView after a onItemClickListener modifies data in an int [] from the ImageAdapter class

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

My `GridView` is created in my `onCreate` here:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
...
```

My `ImageAdapter` class contains an `int[]`"images" of `R.drawable.` references to .png files. I have an onItemClickListener further down in my `onCreate` that will, depending on where and when my `gridview` is touched, will update the "images" array. It looks like this, with a lot of extraneous code stripped out:

```
...
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                while (count <= 6) {
...
                    if (count == 2 && verifyEmpty == false
                            && choosePiece == true && chooseEmpty == true) {
                        verifyEmpty = gc.checkEmptyChoice(position);
                        if (verifyEmpty == true) {
                            gc.moveToEmpty(position, gameBoardModel,
                                    (ImageView) v, selectedLocation);
                            count++;
                            // UPDATE THE GRIDVIEW SOMEHOW HERE.
                        }
                        break;
                    }
...
```

**I want to update my `gridview` right after the `count++` inside the nested `if`. The method right above it, `gc.moveToEmpty(...)` will make changes to the `images` array and I want those changes reflected in the `gridview`**.
I have attempted using `notifyDataSetChanged()` and `invalidateViews` but cannot make either of them work from inside my `onItemClickListener`.

-------------------SOLUTION--------------FROM ANSWER BELOW-----------------

Had to add a name to the ImageAdapter:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageAdapter iA = new ImageAdapter(this);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(iA);
...
```

needed to be final so the the `onClick...` could use it. Then I could reference it like so:

```
                    if (verifyEmpty == true) {
                        gc.moveToEmpty(position, gameBoardModel,
                                (ImageView) v, selectedLocation);
                        count++;
                        // UPDATE THE GRIDVIEW SOMEHOW HERE.
                        // LIKE THIS!
                        iA.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save a reference to your `ImageAdapter` and then call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29):

```
imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Which notifies the adapter that the underlying data has changed and it should refresh.

Comment: I tried adding a name to my ImageAdapter but Eclipse told me I had an error. I'll try again.

Comment: Ok, that appears to have worked. I forgot to put the `Context` argument the first time I think.